# What is the convention on using extraneous `this` references in a class?

Tags: oop, this

What is the convention for using the `this` keyword when it is extraneous? For example, consider the following class declaration:

```
class Test {
   private int privateVariable;

   public Test(int constructorVariable) {

     this.privateVariable = constructorVariable;

   }
}
```

The `this` before `privateVariable` in the constructor is extraneous, but it makes the code slightly more understandable (in my opinion). So do you use it like this, or not?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth In Java it is extraneous unless `constructorVariable` and `privateVariable` share a name. http://ideone.com/00EVCZ vs http://ideone.com/HUb6R9

Comment: Our coding standards, quite rightly enforced through static code analysis, enforce "this". I must say I prefer it, its a language feature which denotes an instance of the enclosing class better than mMemberVariable or _memberVariable I'd say.  This  post will prob get closed by Stack Overflow Zealots, "its meta baby", will  be the cry......I Like the question anyway so +1'd it.

Comment: @HobbitHole: Oh, yeah, misread your code :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the most part it's a matter of personal/team preference.  There are some cases where it's structurally meaningful.  For example, consider the Java conventions of providing values for `final` class members in a constructor:

```
private final int someValue;

public SomeClass(int someValue) {
    this.someValue = someValue;
}
```

In this case the `this` keyword is needed to explicitly define which of the two identically-named variables are being referenced in that same scope.  Given this approach, it's often preferred by teams to explicitly reference values with `this` rather than muck with the names, such as:

```
private final int _someValue;

public SomeClass(int someValue) {
    _someValue = someValue;
}
```

(I'm not 100% certain if Java would complain about that, but C# wouldn't, aside from the `final` keyword of course.)  This is effectively doing the same thing, but it prepends a potentially ugly underscore to a value which has no use elsewhere.  Conversely, prepending the underscore (or any other such unnecessary decoration) to the method parameter would advertise it in the intellisense and generated documentation, which is also undesirable.

So while it comes down to preference, often times that preference is grounded in a well intentioned desire to keep names consistent and meaningful.

Comment: Referring back to my example, if `privateVariable` and `constructorVariable` share a name, the `this` is obviously required so the language can distinguish which variable you are referring to. Just to clarify, besides that, it's just personal preference?

Comment: @HobbitHole: It really is personal preference, ya.  There *may* be some languages where it's required (I certainly can't speak for every language), and in those languages I imagine the error of omitting it would be pretty clear at compile/interpret time.  Some code analysis tools enforce this preference, or can be configured to enforce it.  Personally I try to shy away from "coding standards" like that which enforce a policy without regard to the meaning and context of the particular code being written.  But that, too, is just my personal preference.  As long as the code is clear and concise.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the styleguide you (or your company) are using. If you don't have one, [this document](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2005/01/26/361363.aspx) is a good start and also supports your suggestion.

Other styleguides -- especially when derived from other languages as for instance c++ -- prefer prefixing private members with _ or m_

```
private int _privateVariable;
private int m_privateVariable;
```

or may even use hungarian notation  (see [this article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html) for dos and don'ts)

```
private string m_strPrivateVariable;
```

If you are in charge of making the decision, read some articles, chose what fits your needs and preferences best. But after the decision is made, stick to it and enforce it.